# How to Update .NetCore SDK 2.1 to 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have my .Net Core project running on version 2.1 i have installed .Net core 3.1 in VS.

my hosting platform requires 2.2 version and above. How can i update my project to a higher version (3.1) from PM Console or other approaches.

[image: core]

the picture above is a snapshot of my present SDK version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should migrate your project using instructions:

1. 2.1 to 2.2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/21-to-22?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio
2. 2.2 to 3.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio
3. 3.0 to 3.1: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/30-to-31?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio